Does $\frac{\zeta(s,\,{\small1/4})}{\zeta(s,\,{\small3/4})}={\small\pm}1$ imply $\left|\frac{\zeta(s)\,\beta(1-s)}{\beta(s)\,\zeta(1-s)}\right|=1$?
Motivated by the following Riemann Hypothesis approach: 
$\,\zeta(s)$ Riemann Zeta,
$\,\beta(s)$ Dirichlet Beta,
$\,\zeta(s,a)$ Hurwitz Zeta  
By function definitions, 
$$ 
\begin{align} 
\left(1-2^{-s}\right)4^{s}\zeta\left(s\right) &= \zeta\left(s,{\small1/4}\right) {\color{red}+} \zeta\left(s,{\small3/4}\right) \\[2mm] 
4^{s}\beta\left(s\right) &= \zeta\left(s,{\small1/4}\right) {\color{red}-} \zeta\left(s,{\small3/4}\right) 
\end{align} 
$$
Thus, 
$$ 
\begin{align} 
4^{{\small1/2}-s}\zeta\left(s,{\small1/4}\right) &= \left(1-2^{-s}\right)\zeta\left(s\right) {\color{red}+} \beta\left(s\right) \\[2mm] 
4^{{\small1/2}-s}\zeta\left(s,{\small3/4}\right) &= \left(1-2^{-s}\right)\zeta\left(s\right) {\color{red}-} \beta\left(s\right)
\end{align} 
$$
And, 
$$ 
\begin{align} 
{\small\left(1-2^{-s}\right)}\zeta\left(s\right).\beta\left(s\right)=0 &\Rightarrow {\zeta\left(s,{\small1/4}\right)}/{\zeta\left(s,{\small3/4}\right)}={\small\pm}1 \\[2mm] 
\zeta\left(s,{\small1/4}\right).\zeta\left(s,{\small3/4}\right)=0 &\Rightarrow {{\small\left(1-2^{-s}\right)}\zeta\left(s\right)}/{\beta\left(s\right)}={\small\pm}1 
\end{align} 
$$
On the other hand, 
By functional equations, 
$$ 
\begin{align} 
\zeta\left(1-s\right)/\zeta\left(s\right) &= 2^{1-s}\,\pi^{-s}\,\cos\left(\pi\,s/2\right)\,\Gamma\left(s\right) \\[2mm] 
\beta\left(1-s\right)/\beta\left(s\right) &= 2^{s}\,\,\,\,\,\,\pi^{-s}\,\sin\left(\pi\,s/2\right)\,\Gamma\left(s\right) 
\end{align} 
$$
Hence, for $\,\color{blue}{\left\{ {\small s=a+ib,\,a\in[0,1],\,b\gg0} \right\}}\,$ 
$$ 
\begin{align} 
\frac{\zeta\left(s\right)\beta\left(1-s\right)}{\beta\left(s\right)\zeta\left(1-s\right)} &= 4^{s-{\small1/2}}\,\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\,s\right) 
\,\,\,{\color{blue}{\left\{ {\small\approx{\normalsize{i}}\,4^{s-1/2}} \right\}}} \\[2mm] 
\left|\frac{\zeta\left(s\right)\beta\left(1-s\right)}{\beta\left(s\right)\zeta\left(1-s\right)}\right| &= 
4^{a-{\small1/2}}\,\frac{\sqrt{\sin^2\left(\pi\,a\right)+\sinh^2\left(\pi\,b\right)}}{\cos\left(\pi\,a\right)+\cosh\left(\pi\,b\right)} 
\end{align} 
$$
And, by this promising symmetric behavior, 

For $\left\{ s\in\mathbb{C},\,\,\Re(s)\in(0,1),\,\,\Im(s)\gt0\right\}$, 
How to prove (or disprove) the symmetric flipping effect of:
$$ 
\begin{align}
\color{blue}{\frac{\zeta(s,{\small1/4})}{\zeta(s,{\small3/4})} = \frac{\zeta(s,{\small3/4})}{\zeta(s,{\small1/4})} \Rightarrow 
\left|\frac{\zeta(s)\beta(1-s)}{\beta(s)\zeta(1-s)}\right| = \left|\frac{\beta(s)\zeta(1-s)}{\zeta(s)\beta(1-s)}\right|} 
\end{align}
$$


General Ideas: 
Seeking a sort of symmetric writing, let:
${\color{blue}{\xi(s)}} = {\small\left(1-2^{-s}\right)}\zeta\left(s\right),\,\, {\color{blue}{\beta(s)}} = \beta\left(s\right),\,\, {\color{blue}{\lambda(s)}} = \zeta\left(s,{\small1/4}\right),\,\, {\color{blue}{\delta(s)}} = \zeta\left(s,{\small3/4}\right) $ 
$$ 
\begin{align} 
&\frac{\xi({\small{s}})\,\beta({\small{1-s}}) \,{\color{red}-}\, \beta({\small{s}})\,\xi({\small{1-s}})}{\xi({\small{s}})\,\beta({\small{1-s}}) \,{\color{red}+}\, \beta({\small{s}})\,\xi({\small{1-s}})} = {\color{red}-}\,\frac{\lambda({\small{s}})\,\delta({\small{1-s}}) \,{\color{red}-}\, \delta({\small{s}})\,\lambda({\small{1-s}})} {\lambda({\small{s}})\,\lambda({\small{1-s}}) \,{\color{red}-}\, \delta({\small{s}})\,\delta({\small{1-s}})} \tag{1} \\[1mm] 
&\frac{\xi({\small{s}})\,\beta({\small{1-\overline{s}}}) \,{\color{red}-}\, \beta({\small{s}})\,\xi({\small{1-\overline{s}}})}{\xi({\small{s}})\,\beta({\small{1-\overline{s}}}) \,{\color{red}+}\, \beta({\small{s}})\,\xi({\small{1-\overline{s}}})} = {\color{red}-}\,\frac{\lambda({\small{s}})/\delta({\small{s}}) \,{\color{red}-}\, \lambda({\small{1-\overline{s}}})/\delta({\small{1-\overline{s}}})} {\lambda({\small{s}})\lambda({\small{1-\overline{s}}}) / \delta({\small{s}})\delta({\small{1-\overline{s}}}) {\color{red}-}1} \tag{2} \\ 
\end{align} 
$$
If either $(1)$ or $(2)$ is pure imaginary at ${\lambda({\small{z}})}/{\delta({\small{z}})}={\small\pm}1$ 
Then $\,\,\displaystyle \lim_{s \to z}\left|\xi({\small{s}})\beta({\small{1-s}}) / \beta({\small{s}})\xi({\small{1-s}})\right|=1\,$.  
Also, a nice formula is:
$$
\begin{align}
\,&{\color{red}+} \frac{\xi({\small{s}})\beta({\small{1-s}})\,{\color{red}-}\,\beta({\small{s}})\xi({\small{1-s}})}{\xi({\small{s}})\beta({\small{1-s}})\,{\color{red}+}\,\beta({\small{s}})\xi({\small{1-s}})}\,\,
\frac{\xi({\small{s}})\xi({\small{1-s}})\,{\color{red}+}\,\beta({\small{s}})\beta({\small{1-s}})}{\xi({\small{s}})\xi({\small{1-s}})\,{\color{red}-}\,\beta({\small{s}})\beta({\small{1-s}})}= \\ 
\,&{\color{red}-} \frac{\lambda({\small{s}})\delta({\small{1-s}})\,{\color{red}-}\,\delta({\small{s}})\lambda({\small{1-s}})}{\lambda({\small{s}})\delta({\small{1-s}})\,{\color{red}+}\,\delta({\small{s}})\lambda({\small{1-s}})}\,\,
\frac{\lambda({\small{s}})\lambda({\small{1-s}})\,{\color{red}+}\,\delta({\small{s}})\delta({\small{1-s}})}{\lambda({\small{s}})\lambda({\small{1-s}})\,{\color{red}-}\,\delta({\small{s}})\delta({\small{1-s}})} 
\end{align}
$$
Where applying this transform for either 
$\{\xi,\beta\}$ or $\{\lambda,\delta\}$ result on equality. 

General Thoughts: 
In his paper (Riemann's Hypothesis - 2019), Brian Conrey wrote: 
" 7. Why Do We Think RH is True: The main reason is ... that 
something so incredibly symmetric should be true in mathematics. "  
Although, Riemann Zeta function has an incredible symmetric behavior (basically due to its Riemann functional equation), this symmetry had not been utilized in any will known RH approach. Perhaps the presence of Gamma function in the functional equation is the main reason behind that. The main uses of the symmetry is for checking, calculation, and/or approximation purposes (i.e. Gram Point).  
Nevertheless, imagen RH as a coin, has $\zeta(s)$ as a Head, and the Zeta symmetry is shining from this Head with no helpful use by itself alone. Then imagen $\beta(s)$ as the Tail of the RH coin, with the same Beta symmetry shining from this Tail, completing the missing useful use of the combined symmetry by replacing the annoying $\Gamma(s)$ with the pleasing believe of both $\,\zeta,\,\beta\,$ obey RH. 
Good Luck.


note that that are many similar functions to zeta that satisfy similar symmetry relations but do not have zeroes on the critical line only (look up Davenport Heilbronn)

@Conrad, I am aware of Davenport-Heilbronn L-function. Nonetheless, the approach in the question is using the Dirichlet Beta function specifically, which -like Riemann Zeta- is widely believed to obey RH. I added a Figure that illustrate the zeros of $\zeta,\beta$ and their corresponding to Arg $\zeta_{1/4},\zeta_{3/4}$. Anyhow, it seems that people didn't like the question, I shall deleted it soon. Thanks.

I believe $\beta(s)=0\implies \frac{\zeta\left(s,\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\zeta\left(s,\frac{3}{4}\right)}=1$, so perhaps $\frac{\zeta\left(s,\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\zeta\left(s,\frac{3}{4}\right)}=1$ along the critical line $s=\frac{1}{2}+i t$ only at the non-trivial zeros of $\beta(s)$?

I still do not get what is the question - to me it seems that by definition $\zeta(s,1/4)=\pm \zeta(s,3/4)$ implies $s$ is a zero of zeta, beta or $s=0$ so does the question ask is the zero on the critical line if $\Re s>0$ so in another words is RH (and analogue for beta) true?

@Steven showed that is not true since $s=0$ satisfies LHS with minus but RHS is trivially $0$

Again not sure what is the question anymore - do you have any restrictions on $s$ as the above comment is very unclear - can you post the exact question in the body of the problem including all relevant details like what $s$ is allowed etc - the post is just a ton of verbiage that is very confusing while the title has no conditions on $s$

You also need to account for the trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ where I believe $\frac{\zeta\left(s,\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\zeta\left(s,\frac{3}{4}\right)}$ evaluates to $-1$ and $\frac{\zeta(s), \beta(1-s)}{\beta(s), \zeta(1-s)}$ evaluates to zero, and also the trivial zeros of $\beta(s)$ where I believe $\frac{\zeta\left(s,\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\zeta\left(s,\frac{3}{4}\right)}$ evaluates to $1$ and $\frac{\zeta(s), \beta(1-s)}{\beta(s), \zeta(1-s)}$ exhibits complex infinities (poles).

So perhaps your conjecture is equivalent to $$\frac{\zeta\left(s,\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\zeta\left(s,\frac{3}{4}\right)}=\pm1\land\Re(s)=\frac{1}{2}\implies \zeta(s)=0\lor \beta(s)=0$$ or perhaps more specifically $$\text{Assuming }\Re(s)=\frac{1}{2},\quad \left{\substack{\frac{\zeta\left(s,\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\zeta\left(s,\frac{3}{4}\right)}=-1\implies \zeta(s)=0 \ \frac{\zeta\left(s,\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\zeta\left(s,\frac{3}{4}\right)}=1\implies\beta(s)=0}\right}?$$

or in other words prove more or less the RH for $\zeta$ or $\beta$ as for $z=\sigma+it, t>0$ we have $|\tan \pi z/2-i| < \frac{2e^{-\pi t/2}}{1-e^{-\pi t/2}}$ while $|4^{z-1/2}|=4^{\sigma-1/2}$ which already for $t>10$ would imply that any such $z$ which is a nontrivial root of either $\zeta$ or $\beta$ is very close in real part to $1/2$; so stripped to the bones this question essentially asks us to prove RH; as I noted in my first comment and is seen in the counterexamples presented, the result cannot follow just from general symmetry principles which would imply it for all complex $s$

@Conrad, Finally, this is a useful note. Thanks!. So, according to your note (and up to my understanding), we cann't expected the result to follow by the symmetry, because if it's true, then it should be true for the whole complex plan, not only inside the critical strip. Would you please explain the general symmetry principle a bit more for me. Appreciating your efforts.

My point is that you propose a conjecture about entire functions with some properties in the linked question  which as we see here it's not true in general since you need to restrict the values of $s$ quite arbitrarily here (the restriction taking into account specific properties of zeta and beta while your proposed conjecture was very general); this invalidates imho this approach from the point of view that uses only general symmetries

@Conrad, I got your point. I made a mistake when I linked the two questions. This causes a misleading in the current questions. I shall rephrase the question and remove the link to the previous conjecture (the general case), in order to point out the purpose of this questions, which is to ask about the validity of this approach to RH, and with my commitment to delete if it is not useful. Many thanks again.

I illustrated the Riemann hypothesis implies your conjecture in the critical strip in my answer below, and I suspect your conjecture is false assuming the Riemann hypothesis is false. What leads you to believe your conjecture would be true even if the Riemann hypothesis is false?

Assume that
$$f(s)=\frac{\zeta(s)\, \beta(1-s)}{\beta(s)\, \zeta(1-s)}=\frac{4^{2 s-1} \zeta(s) \left(\zeta\left(1-s,\frac{1}{4}\right)-\zeta\left(1-s,\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)}{\zeta(1-s)\left(\zeta\left(s,\frac{1}{4}\right)-\zeta\left(s,\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)}\tag{1}$$
and
$$g(s)=\frac{\zeta\left(s,\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\zeta\left(s,\frac{3}{4}\right)}\tag{2}.$$

The case
$$g(s)=-1\implies |f(s)|=1\tag{3}$$
is false since $g(0)=-1$ and $f(0)=0$, and also I believe $g(s)=-1$ and $f(s)=0$ when $s$ is a trivial zero of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$.

Note that $\zeta(s)$ can be evaluated as
$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{2^s \left(2^s-1\right)} \left(\zeta\left(s,\frac{1}{4}\right)+\zeta\left(s,\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)\tag{4}$$
where the function $\frac{1}{2^s \left(2^s-1\right)}$ is a meromorphic function of $s$ with poles of order $1$ at
$$s=\frac{2 \pi c i}{\log(2)}\,,\quad c\in\mathbb{Z}\tag{5}$$
and consequently the condition $g(s)=-1$ corresponds to a zero of $\zeta(s)$ except at a pole of $\frac{1}{2^s \left(2^s-1\right)}$.

For the case $s=0$ mentioned above corresponding to $c=0$ in formula (5) above, the zero of $\left(\zeta\left(s,\frac{1}{4}\right)+\zeta\left(s,\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)$ at $s=0$ is cancelled by the pole of $\frac{1}{2^s \left(2^s-1\right)}$ at $s=0$ and formula (4) above evaluates to $\zeta(0)=\frac{1}{2}$ in a limit sense.

I believe the other poles of $\frac{1}{2^s \left(2^s-1\right)}$ along the imaginary axis are contradictions to your revised claim of
$$g(s)=\pm1\implies |f(s)|=1\,,\quad\Re(s)\in[0,1]\land s\ne0\land s\ne1\tag{6}.$$

The case
$$g(s)=1\implies |f(s)|=1\tag{7}$$
is also false since $g(s)=1$ when $s=-2 n+1\land n\in\mathbb{N}$ which are the non-trivial zeros of the Dirichlet beta function $\beta(s)$ where $f(s)$ exhibits complex infinities (poles).

Note the Dirichlet beta function $\beta(s)$ can be evaluated as
$$\beta(s)=2^{-2 s} \left(\zeta\left(s,\frac{1}{4}\right)-\zeta \left(s,\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)\tag{8}$$
where the function $2^{-2 s}$ is an analytic function of $s$ and consequently the condition $g(s)=1$ corresponds to a zero of $\beta(s)$.

Since $g(s)=1$ corresponds to a zero of $\beta(s)$, $g(s)=-1$ corresponds to a zero of $\zeta(s)$ when $Re(s)\ne 0$, and $|f(s)|=1$ along the critical line, the Riemann hypothesis implies your conjecture is true in the critical strip, but I don't see how your conjecture provides any meaningful insight into the Riemann hypothesis.

I've wondered for quite some time whether a non-trivial zero of $\zeta(s)$ which violates the Riemann hypothesis would require a contour line of $\left|\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(1-s)}\right|=1$ to pass through it (which was the fundamental motivation for this question I asked on MSE in late 2018), and likewise I wonder whether a non-trivial zero of $\beta(s)$ which violates the Riemann hypothesis would require a contour line of $\left|\frac{\beta(s)}{\beta(1-s)}\right|=1$ to pass through it. But even if both of these are true, I see no reason why a non-trivial zero of $\zeta(s)$ which violates the Riemann hypothesis would require a contour line of $\left|\frac{\beta(s)}{\beta(1-s)}\right|=1$ to pass through it, and likewise I see no reason why a non-trivial zero of $\beta(s)$ which violates the Riemann hypothesis would require a contour line of $\left|\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(1-s)}\right|=1$ to pass through it.

Evaluations seem to suggest that the trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ and $\beta(s)$ are enclosed by contours of $\left|\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(1-s)}\right|=1$ and $\left|\frac{\beta(s)}{\beta(1-s)}\right|=1$ rather than having these contours pass directly through them, and this raises the quesion in my mind whether non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ and $\beta(s)$ which violate the Riemann hypothesis would exhibit a similar phenomenon. But the question in the previous paragraph is perhaps more valid because of the symmetry of the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ and $\beta(s)$ in the critical strip.

Finally, I suspect your conjecture is true in the critical strip if-and-only if the Riemann hypothesis is true.

Since,
$$ |f(s)|=\left|\frac{\zeta\left(s\right)\beta\left(1-s\right)}{\beta\left(s\right)\zeta\left(1-s\right)}\right| =
4^{a-{\small1/2}},\frac{\sqrt{\sin^2\left(\pi,a\right)+\sinh^2\left(\pi,b\right)}}{\cos\left(\pi,a\right)+\cosh\left(\pi,b\right)} $$
Hence,
a) the only case where the nominator vanish is $(a=0, b=0)$, which correspond to Zeta pole at $s=1$,
b) other than ${s=0 \Rightarrow 1-s=1}$, $|f(s)|$ never vanish, c) clearly $|f(s)|=1$ for $a=1/2$.

note that $g(s)=1$ implies by definition $\beta(s)=0$ and it is known there are no solutions in the critical strip $0<\Re s <1$ with $\Re s \ne 1/2$ up to large $t$

@HazemOrabi Sorry, I don't see how your conjecture provides any insight into the Riemann hypothesis since to prove your conjecture false its seems to me one would have to locate a non-trivial zeta-zero off the critical line which would in-of-itself be a proof that the Riemann hypothesis is false.
